# Loop doing strange things with data

Tags: python, sql, loops, tkinter

Ok so I have been working on this problem for around 8 hours now and I just can't figure out what is happening. So the application I am making is a TimeSheet manager which uses an android app; a desktop app which I am making in python; and an MySQL database. The desktop app pretty much just uses queries on the Database. So the current query is for the user to check the amount of hours an employee has done between two date:

```
query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, StartTime, FinishTime FROM Sheets WHERE DateTesting >= '"+StartDate+"' AND DateTesting <= '"+EndDate+"';"
```

And then the python application displays the results by using date time to take the start time and end time and work out the amount of hours the employee worked. This is working ok.

```
        tdelta = datetime.datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
        tdelta=(str(tdelta))
        totalDelta.append(tdelta)

        self.labels.append(Label(myframe,text=f'Name: {a} {b} | Start Time: {c} | Finish Time: {d} | Hours Done: {tdelta}'))
        self.labels[q].grid(column=0, row=+r)
```

FYI it uses a loop to loop through the information. The next part (which I am having the issue with) is to calculate total the hours EACH employee has done, but my loop is awful and I am at the point of just being brain blocked.

```
    for u in secondNameList:
        totalHoursPerPerson = 0
        totalMinutesPerPerson = 0    
        for item in nameList:
            if item == u:
                timeParts = [int(s) for s in tdelta.split(':')]
                totalMinutesPerPerson += timeParts[1]
                totalHoursPerPerson += timeParts[0] 
                totalHoursPerPerson += totalMinutes // 60
                minutesToTake = totalMinutes // 60
                minutesToSub = minutesToTake * 60
                totalMinutesPerPerson = totalMinutes - minutesToSub
                print(totalHoursPerPerson)
                totalsPerPerson.append(f'{item} did a total of {totalHoursPerPerson} Hours')
                print(f'{item} did a total of {totalHoursPerPerson} Hours')

    totalsPerPerson = list(set(totalsPerPerson))
    print(totalsPerPerson)
```

The Output as shown below:

```
4
['Chris', 'Chris', 'Rory', 'John']
['Chris', 'Chris', 'Rory', 'John']
(('Chris', 'Gracey', '07:00', '16:30'), ('Chris', 'Gracey', '07:00', '16:30'), ('Rory', 'Gracey', '07:00', '16:30'), ('John', 'Smith', '07:00', '16:30'))
9
Chris did a total of 9 Hours
18
Chris did a total of 18 Hours
9
Chris did a total of 9 Hours
18
Chris did a total of 18 Hours
9
Rory did a total of 9 Hours
9
John did a total of 9 Hours
['John did a total of 9 Hours', 'Chris did a total of 18 Hours', 'Rory did a total of 9 Hours', 'Chris did a total of 9 Hours']
```

I'm really not sure why it is displaying Chris twice. I also tried removing duplicates but it just breaks it even more.

If there is a better way of doing this I am all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed the  sql statement instead.

This is the statement I used:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(FinishTime) - TIME_TO_SEC(StartTime))) AS timediff FROM Sheets WHERE DateTesting >= '2018/5/7' AND DateTesting <= '2018/5/18' GROUP BY FirstName, LastName;
```

Of course with variables set in python.